# Como puedo resolver este problema de Intent?

Tags: android-intent

En mi programa tengo dos activity, el primero llama al al segundo usando Intent, el segundo le devuelve algunas variables String y retorna al primero también usando Intent, el problema está en que tengo error por al iniciar la 1ra activity por que hay un bundle sin datos; aunque aparentemente no tiene lógica, esto solo es un trozo de código para tratar de explicar mi problema.
Como puedo resolver esto, sería posible indicar al programa que al iniciarse por primera vez no llame el bunde y después de haber llamado a la 2da activity ya se ejecute...?

Aqui esta mi 1ra activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mDumpTextView;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private Button mBotonSend;
private EditText mTextoEditor1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    mBotonSend = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton ) ;
    mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1_ReadValues);
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1_Scroller);
    mTextoEditor1 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.et1_WriteValues );

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String textoImportado2=bundle.getString("texto2");
    mDumpTextView.setText(textoImportado2);

    mBotonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PreferenceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("texto1", mTextoEditor1.getText().toString());
            mTextoEditor1.setText( "" );

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Y aqui esta mi 2da activity

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mDumpTextView;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private EditText mTextoEditor1;
private Button mBotonSend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main2 );

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String textoImportado1=bundle.getString("texto1");

    mTextoEditor1 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.et1_WriteValues );
    mBotonSend = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton ) ;
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1_Scroller);
    TextView mDumpTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1_ReadValues);

    mDumpTextView.setText(textoImportado1);

    mBotonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("texto2", mTextoEditor1.getText().toString());
            mTextoEditor1.setText( "" );
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Quien inicia la primera activity para que le llegue un bundle en un intent?

Comment: Ese es mi problema, la primera vez que se ejecuta el MainActivity no hay datos todavía en el bundle, por requerimientos de mi programa primero se tiene que ejecutar MainActivity, luego al presionar mBotonSend de esta actividad se lanza la PreferenceActivity, luego despues  de precionar el otro mBotonSend de  esta 2da actividad se regresa al MainActivity...

Answer (score 1):

Si el `Activity` arranca sin un Intent, entonces `getIntent()` devuelve `null`.

Para el caso que comentás, en `onCreate()` podés hacer:

```
boolean tengoBundle = false;
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = null;
if(intent != null){
   extras = intent.getExtras();
   tengoBundle = true;
}
```

El `tengoBundle` es optativo, es solo imaginando que hay partes del código que deberán tener un comportamiento default si no hay `Bundle` de donde sacar los datos y podés usar esta variable para determinar el flujo del programa.

*Ejemplo:*

```
String textoImportado2=""; //Default;
if(tengoBundle){
   textoImportado2 = bundle.getString("texto2");
}
```